# Django Celery application - No module named celery error

Tags: django-celery

I have created a django-celery application as in the tutorial at:

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/django/first-steps-with-django.html

Everything works fine when I run it without application parameter as in:

```
$ python manage.py celery worker -l info
```

but I can't start it at all with the application parameter, as in:

```
$ python manage.py celery worker -A myapp -l info
```

where myapp is the name given to the application when I created the project with:

```
$ python manage.py startapp myapp
```

The error that I am getting is:

```
ImportError: No module named celery
```

Does anyone know why this happens and how to solve it?

Comment: `-A` argument is for celery applications, not for Django applications... They are not used by django-celery at the moment.

Comment: ah, I didn't know that. Thanks for the answer. But then how can I run this?

Comment: Celery 3.1 will support django from scratch (but does not have all of the features from django-celery, e.g no database result backend and no database periodic task scheduler, but you can still use djcelery on top to get that)

Comment: Example using celery with django in celery 3.1 (dev): https://github.com/celery/celery/tree/master/examples/django

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Edit April 2014:**

The Celery docs have been updated for 3.1; the below solution is now outdated, see:

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/django/first-steps-with-django.html

---

By default, celery searches for a module named `celery.py` to find its configuration. You can get celery to use a different name than `celery.py` by specify [it on the app argument](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/next-steps.html#about-the-app-argument) - in this example, we'll look for celery config in `settings.py`:

```
python manage.py celery worker --app=myapp.settings
```

When using `django-celery` you can either use the above call to start celery, or do as I originally did and create a `celery.py` in my application package `myapp`:

```
from settings import celery
```

My Django `settings.py` contains the normal celery config:

```
from celery import Celery

celery = Celery(broker="amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1:5672//")

celery.conf.update(
    CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = "myapp",
    CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE = "myapp",
    CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE_TYPE = "direct",
    CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY = "myapp",
)
```

Then run the celery worker like this:

```
python manage.py celery worker --app=myapp
```

Just for clarity's sake, here's my full application structure:

```
myproject/
    manage.py
    myapp/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        celery.py
```

Comment: i'm voting +1 because this helped me realize that celery config is a bit of black magic and I have to be careful.  But you should edit your answer because it's inconsistent.  Why do you have a celery.py file if you're setting up celery in settings.py?  Or did you mean to say you're setting it up in celery.py?

Comment: Just updated the answer, based on a better understanding I now have :) @Milimetric I have a celery.py file which imports settings.py, as that is what celery looks for by default.

Comment: If your code is working, and it's open source, a link would be great.  Thanks for the edit.

Comment: @Milimetric Sorry I don't have a link to a specific example. I use Flask on open-source projects.. Can you not get the above working?

Comment: no, i'm having some crazy unrelated problem.  I have `from celery import Celery` in a folder along with what's probably bad configuration.  Here's the crazy part:  when I try to run any other working examples, it goes to that *other* folder and says `ImportError: cannot import name Celery`

Comment: I think some of the celery examples I've tried do something really nasty to sys.path.  Basically I end up with this problem: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/pythonmac-sig/2010-June/022372.html  So people beware, your sys.path might get screwed up and you need to fix it and probably stay away from `from __future__ import absolute_import`

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you're trying to start the celery worker from a directory that has access to the celery module.  In my case I was trying to start the worker from the app directory rather than the project.