# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'celery'

Tags: python, django

I was trying to make e-commerce with a third party application in Django called saleor whenever I try to migrate this error show up

```
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'celery'
```

I tried to manually install celery  and still, I am sure that I   activated my  virtual environment

```
File "C:\Users\moustafa gebril\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 131, in check_apps_ready
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Users\moustafa gebril\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\moustafa gebril\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\moustafa gebril\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 107, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\moustafa gebril\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\moustafa gebril\allh\saleor\saleor\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .celeryconf import app as celery_app
  File "C:\Users\moustafa gebril\allh\saleor\saleor\celeryconf.py", line 3, in <module>
    from celery import Celery
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'celery'
```

Comment: Show us your code and the full stack trace of the error.

Comment: I think this is all that you needed [https://stackoverflow.com/a/15914692/6808714]

Comment: install **pip install celery**

Answer (score 0):

run this command to install celery

```
pip install celery
```

and definitely mention that in Django settings INSTALLED APPS section.